# Views multi-value 'smart' separator "comma" or "and"

Tags: 7, views

So I have a multi-value field which I want to separate with commas, but have the last value separated by " and ".

So for example, multi value field values

> Array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")

I wish to output this as:

> Apple, Orange and Banana

But using the "simple separator" won't do this. I also tried 2 views hooks `hook_views_pre_render` and `hook_views_post_render` but can't figure out how to achieve this. Do I need to render the whole view again into `$output`? If so how do I go about doing this? Or does anyone have a simpler solution? A contrib module maybe?

Thanks.